# The aiohttp GET request returns nothing, as if the console is frozen

Tags: python, python-3.x, async-await, python-asyncio, aiohttp

The aiohttp GET request returns nothing, as if the console is frozen. At the same time, requests.get with the same headers returns everything. How can I fix it?

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import ssl
import certifi


url = "https://ru.farnell.com/browse-for-products"
ssl_context = ssl.create_default_context(cafile=certifi.where())
headers = {
    'accept': '* / *',
    'accept - encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept - language': 'ru - RU, ru; q = 0.9, en - US; q = 0.8, en; q = 0.7',
    'cache - control': 'no - cache',
    "User-Agent": UserAgent().Opera
}

async def gather_data():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        response = await session.get(url=url, headers=headers, ssl=ssl_context)
        await print(response)


if name == "main":
    asyncio.run(gather_data())
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of different problems. First you print the response object, not the body of the response. To get they you need to use `await response.text()`. Then you await `print`, which you can’t do since `print` returns `None`, not an awaitable.

Your code should look more like.

```
async def gather_data():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        response = await session.get(url=url, headers=headers, ssl=ssl_context)
        print(await response.text())
```

Also note that your example, in a vacuum, doesn’t benefit from asyncio. That may or may not matter depending on what your real code looks like.